# Django AdminDocs with Uppercase App Names

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to implement Django's Admin Docs (`django.contrib.admindocs`) into my project. I've now realized that the best practice for app names is to be lower case, as the generated urls default to a lowercase url name.

For example, my app name is Projects:

```
Stores all Project entries, related to :model:`Projects.Project`
```

On the admin page, the generated url leads to `admin/doc/models/projects.project/` instead of `admin/doc/models/Projects.project/`

Is there an easy way to resolve this without having to rename every app in my project?

When manually changing the url to the app name (uppercase), the page works as intended.